# Can we create an app for our clients without publicly listing it in the App Exchange?

Tags: appexchange, app

Q: Do we need to publish on the AppExchange in our order for our customers to install our app to their SFDC instance?

Backstory: We're preparing an app for our clients that is designed to render as a new Tab as well as an additional component viewed within their individual Accounts pages. This app will speak to our own platform and will be fully authenticated. At this juncture, the additional marketing exposure provided by the App Exchange is not required.

Comment: If you have IPR and/or plan to sell to multiple clients, it has to be on the AppExchange, though you don't have to have a public listing. You can make the listing private. Note, however, that you will have to go through security review either way.

Comment: What if the app is technically free as part of our product sold outside of AppExchange?

Comment: I found this old comment saying otherwise but perhaps that is no longer accurate:  https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/133983/87571

Comment: I suggest you check with your account manager or read your master agreement, but AFAIK if you create a managed package for distribution to customers, even if it is free, you have to be a partner and the package it needs to go through security review, which means it needs to be associated with your LMO and have a private AppExchange listing with business plan. You can, of course, provide an unlocked package, where you don't retain IPR and the customer can do what they like with the metadata in that package.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I'm currently working with a client that has several managed and unmanaged packages that are distributed via just the install links. Not listed on AppExchange

Comment: While it isn't publicly listed, do they have a private listing? If not, how are they conforming to Salesforce's master agreement? Is what they are doing actually permitted in their contract with Salesforce? I would be quite concerned...

Comment: @PhilW Not sure how it's done legally but it totally works. With LMA org, developer support, and everything

Comment: Not saying it doesn't technically work, but I believe it violates the Salesforce contracts.

Comment: Oh, and something you cannot do this way is provide patch releases (1GP and 2GP) since this must be enabled by Salesforce and they require you to pass security review before they will do that.